# JMeter integration with AWS getting issue with Config.properties file

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, properties-file

I have integrated successfully JMeter with AWS but I am getting an issue when we run the script . In this we have Config.properties file & we convert .jmx & other data into zip file including Config.properties file in zip folder. But I am getting an issue while reading Config.properties file. My script gets fail.

We have Config.properties file in which I have mention host , No of threads, environment . The reason to make a config.properties file is that a non technical person don't need to go through the script . Just can make a change of no's of users(No's of threads) in Config.properties file. But I am getting an issue while working with AWS distribution  testing . It doesn't work properly & gets fail . Do anyone have idea how to run the .properties file successfully in AWS for Performance testing.

> [image: enter code here]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Container image customization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/container-image.html), it appears that AWS Distributed Load Testing is using [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/) as the wrapper for JMeter tests so you might want to:

1. [Expose the configuration when it comes to the number of threads and so on in Taurus YAML file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables):
2. [Plug in the YAML containing the configuration into main Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Included-Configs)

Example setup:

1. `config.yml`

   ```
   modules:
     jmeter:
       properties:
         threads: 5
         iterations: 2
   ```
2. `test.yml`

   ```
   execution:
   - scenario: simple

   scenarios:
     simple:
       script: test.jmx

   included-configs:
   - config.yaml
   ```
3. `test.jmx` - your original JMeter .jmx script

You can even define your test scenario in Taurus YAML declaratively completely like it's described in [Building Test Plan from Config](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config)

Real life example: [The Complete Guide to API Testing with Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-api-testing)

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will try to implement this !

Comment: Hi Dmitri T ! I have added the images of my script . I have further question . How to call the variable that are present in config.yml file in JMeter ? As I told u earlier I was using .properties file now if I want to call .yml values in threads . How to do so ? Any Idea ?